# Karhunen-Loeve expansion of vector valued random processes

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, kernels

This thesis (https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Karhunen-Loeve-expansions-and-their-applications-Wang/f173dfb99ec4cbd08e779923770466cf1ef3f138) introduces multivariate KL expansion using a generalized Mercer's theorem. The source of the Mercer's theorem as stated by the author is *H.H. Mahram, D. Dahlhaus, and D. Blomker. Karhunen-loeve expansion of vector
random processes. Technical Report, CTL, Swiss Federal Institute of Technology,
No. IKT-NT 1019, 2002.* I have not been able to find any trace of this source on the internet. On this thesis, Mercer's theorem is states as follows:

> Let $X(t)$ be a vector valued random process assume $K(s,t)$ is a is a continuous, symmetric, positive definite multivariate
>   $L^2$ kernel of the stochastic process $X(t).$ $K (s ,t)$ is defined on $T \times T $, where $T$ is a
>   compact interval. Then there exists a $L^2$ orthogonal basis consisting of $\{f_i\}$, which
>   are the eigenfunctions together with the corresponding eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i>0\}$. The kernel $K(s ,t)$ has the representation
>   $$K(s,t)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\lambda_i f_i(s)f_i(t)^T$$ 
>   and the converge is uniform in $s,t$.

I am trying to find the proof of this which is in that technical report. Does anyone know how to access this or have a source that proves this?